# Android project gets java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I add project B to A's java build path:
[image]

and imported packageB in my A.java:

`import com.example.mysensorlistener.MySensorListener;`

but still get runtime error:

```
01-04 18:31:38.533: E/dalvikvm(9746): Could not find class 'com.example.mysensorlistener.MySensorListener', referenced from method com.example.huaweiproj.HuaweiProj.<init>
```

how can i fix that? dont tell me to copy&paste the java file directly....

Comment: Is your `MySensorListener` is **Android Library Project** ???

Comment: @user370305 no, so it must be a library project?

Comment: If `MySensorListener` a `Android Project` then It should be `Android Library Project`, And if it just a **Simple Java Classes Project** the Create a `.jar` file and add that file to Build Path..

Comment: @user370305, yes it's android project, or should i add something here? http://i.stack.imgur.com/G1LdE.png

Comment: Not just `Android Project` It should be `Android Library Project`. And yes you have to add it in `As Library` in Properties of Android Project.

Comment: fixed now, and there is no need to set the 'Java Build Path', thank you all friends~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the project library in the project properties and then try importing it.